# onclick switch div position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Brief Description:**  Need to switch the position of the div's when i click on them.

**Requirement:** If i click on **hello,world** these 2 should switch , if i click on **hello2,world2** those 2 will switch.
Here is my code:

Note - i have switched the div's with a checkbox, note - only the top one is switching, i want to achieve the switching on clicking

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){

  alert("div swapped");
})


$('#check').change(function () {
//alert('check clicked');
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

$('#div1').insertAfter($('#div2'));

} else {

$('#div1').insertBefore($('#div2'));
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div id="div1">Hello</div> 
<div id="div2">World</div>
</div>

<br>
<div>
<div id="div1">Hello2</div> 
<div id="div2">World2</div>
</div>

<br>
 click me to switch Hello,World<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"/>
```

> If i click on hello,world these 2 should switch , if i click on hello2,world2 those 2 will switch.

**Please help.**

Comment: Identifiers in HTML must be __Unique__

Comment: your requirement and your code are saying two different stories

Comment: i have switched the div's with a checkbox, note - only the top one is switching, i want to achieve the switching on clicking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right this is what you're looking for:

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){

  alert("div swapped");
})


$('.click').click(function (evt) {
  var $div = $(evt.target).closest('.switch');
  $div.next('.switch').after($div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">
  <div class="switch">Hello</div> 
  <div class="switch">World</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="click">
  <div class="switch">Hello2</div> 
  <div class="switch">World2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If i am adding this code in my angular `.ts` file - `var div1 = $(evt.target).first('.switch');`  , its saying  [ts] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
 , please help

Comment: Try `.closest()` instead of `.first()`. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, error gone, can you point me to a library from where i can read myself and use these functions

Comment: Those are functions from jQuery. You can read the documentation at [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/)